# Table generation using blockarray?

Tags: matrices, blkarray

I have been puzzled to generate a specific table using blockarray. How should I adjust given MWE to obtain the result in the image?

```
\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
    & \BAmulticolumn{5}{c} & \\
    \begin{block}{c[ccccc]cc}
        & n_{11}   & n_{12} & n_{13} & \dots & n_{1J} & n_{1.} & \\
        & n_{21}   & n_{22} & n_{23} & \dots & n_{2J} & n_{3.} & \\
        & \vdots   & \ddots &        &       & \vdots & n_{2.} & \\
        & n_{I1}   & n_{I2} & n_{I3} & \dots & n_{IJ} & n_{I.} &
    \end{block}
     & n_{.1} & n_{.2} & n_{.3} & \dots & n_{.J} & $\sum n_{ij} = N$
\end{blockarray}
\]
```

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Your code is incomplete and uncompilable, please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Also, it'd help if you said what you don't like about your result, instead of making people guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}
 & \Block{1-5}{V} \\
\Block{4-1}{U}
     & \Block[draw,rounded-corners]{4-5}{}
       n_{11}   & n_{12} & n_{13} & \dots & n_{1J} & n_{1.} \\
     & n_{21}   & n_{22} & n_{23} & \dots & n_{2J} & n_{3.} \\
     & \vdots   & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots & n_{2.} \\
     & n_{I1}   & n_{I2} & n_{I3} & \dots & n_{IJ} & n_{I.} \\
     & n_{.1} & n_{.2} & n_{.3} & \dots & n_{.J} & \displaystyle\sum n_{ij} = N
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Fix a couple of errors and add a smashed and raised *U*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
    & \BAmulticolumn{5}{c}{V} \\
\cline{2-6}
    \begin{block}{c|ccccc|c}
        & n_{11}   & n_{12} & n_{13} & \dots & n_{1J} & n_{1.} \\
        & n_{21}   & n_{22} & n_{23} & \dots & n_{2J} & n_{3.} \\
\raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{$U$}
        & \vdots   & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots & n_{2.} \\
        & n_{I1}   & n_{I2} & n_{I3} & \dots & n_{IJ} & n_{I.} \\
    \end{block}
\cline{2-6}
     & n_{.1} & n_{.2} & n_{.3} & \dots & n_{.J} & \displaystyle\sum n_{ij} = N
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, `blkarray` is not really necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % <--- important

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{V} \\
\cline{2-6}
& n_{11}   & n_{12} & n_{13} & \dots & n_{1J} & n_{1.} \\
& n_{21}   & n_{22} & n_{23} & \dots & n_{2J} & n_{3.} \\
\raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{$U$}
& \vdots   & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots & n_{2.} \\
& n_{I1}   & n_{I2} & n_{I3} & \dots & n_{IJ} & n_{I.} \\
\cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
& n_{.1} & n_{.2} & n_{.3} & \dots & \multicolumn{1}{c}{n_{.J}} &
  \displaystyle\sum n_{ij} = N
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot.

Comment: My whole document turns red when I add in $$; around U, but once I remove it, LaTeX requests $$

Comment: @Sean_TBI_Research `$$` where? In any case, `$$` should never be used in LaTeX.

Comment: This line: \raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{$U$}

Comment: @Sean_TBI_Research Sorry, cannot understand. Which of the two solution are you using? Unchanged? And what do you mean by “the document turns red”? In the editor?

Comment: Correct, in the editor. I am using the array solution, I understand that blkarray is a bit outdated

Comment: @Sean_TBI_Research Sorry, but if the editor thinks that some valid construct is a syntax error, you change the editor. Possible workaround, use `\ensuremath{U}` instead of $U$.